# Conversão decimal para octal

Tags: c, c++

Preciso criar um algoritmo que converta decimal para octal, porem o meu ta convertendo errado, alguém pode me ajuda como seria o certo?

```
  #include <stdio.h>  

int decim(int n)    
{    
    int i,a;    
    int octal;    


    if(n<=7)  
    {  
        octal=n;  
    }  

    else    
    {  

        while(n>=8 )   
            {       
                a=n%8;  
                n=n/8;  
            }  
            n=n%8;

    }

return octal;

}


int main()  
{
    int n,octal;  

    printf("Informe um numero decimal:");  
    scanf("%d",&n);  

    octal=decim(n);  

    printf(" o numero octal eh: %d\n",octal);    



    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O código que tem não faz uso da variável `octal` que é a que utiliza para retornar o valor calculado, logo irá dar sempre o valor aleatório que apanhar na memoria, a menos que entre no primeiro caso de `n<=7`.

Para alem disso também não está a utilizar o `a` que corresponde cada um dos dígitos que vão formar o valor em octal, com a particularidade de eles serem obtidos da direita para a esquerda.

Tentando utilizar ao máximo o código que já tem, e deixa-lo a funcionar precisa de:

- inicializar o `octal` e aumentar o seu valor a cada digito que interpreta
- inicializar o `i` e utiliza-lo como fator de base 10, para criar os dígitos de forma inversa.

Implementando esses pontos que mencionei, ficaria assim:

```
int decim(int n) {
    int i = 1,a; //i inicializado a 1
    int octal = 0; //octal inicializado a 0

    if(n<=7) {
        octal=n;
    }
    else {
        while(n>=8) {
            a=n%8;
            n=n/8;
            octal = octal + a * i; //calculo do octal
            i *= 10; //aumento do fator de base 10
        }
        n=n%8;
        octal = octal + n * i; //mesmo calculo aqui
    }

    return octal;
}
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/arFsLK)

Naturalmente o código pode ser mais compacto e otimizado, mas tentei ao máximo usar o que já tinha ao invés de reescrever a lógica.

Comment: Entendi, vlw mano, esqueci de multiplicar pelo 10 e inicializar o octal e o i, vlw ai

Answer (score 2):

Faltou armazenar os restos da divisão em algum array (dentro do seu else o valor da variável octal não é alterado) e depois inverter para mostrar o resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void decimal_to_octal(int num) {
    int result[15] = {};
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    if(num >= 8) {
        printf("Decimal: %d -> Octal: ", num);

        while(num >= 8) {
            result[i++] = num % 8;
            num = num / 8;  
        }
        result[i] = num;

        // Imprimindo o valor invertido sem os zeros à esquerda
        for(j = i; j >= 0; j--) {
            printf("%d", result[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Decimal: %d -> Octal: %d\n", num, num);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    decimal_to_octal(7); // 7
    decimal_to_octal(10); // 12
    decimal_to_octal(568); // 1070
    decimal_to_octal(3578); // 6772
    return 0;
}
```

Pode verificar a solução no [ideone](https://ideone.com/83utAM).

Answer (score 0):

O problema é o dentro do "while".

A cada passo, você deve somar, ao resultado anterior (variável *octal*), o algarismo encontrado pelo resto da divisão atual, deslocado na sua devida posição (expoente: 10⁰, 10¹, 10², etc.).

O algoritmo seria:

```
while n!=0 {
            octal = octal + i . n%8
            i = i . 10
            n = n/8
            }
```

Inicializando **octal=0** e **i=1**

Nesse caso, não há a necessidade do "if(n<=7).

TESTANDO:

```
                 | octal |    i   |   n   |
inicialização    |     0 |      1 |  5349 |
1º passo (n!=0)  |     5 |     10 |   668 |
2º passo (n!=0)  |    45 |    100 |    83 |
3º passo (n!=0)  |   345 |   1000 |    10 |
4º passo (n!=0)  |  2345 |  10000 |     1 |
5º passo (n!=0)  | 12345 | 100000 |     0 |
6º passo (n=0)          sai do while

                 | octal |    i   |   n   |
inicialização    |     0 |      1 |     5 |
1º passo (n!=0)  |     5 |     10 |     0 |
2º passo (n=0)          sai do while

                 | octal |    i   |   n   |
inicialização    |     0 |      1 |     0 |
1º passo (n=0)          sai do while
```